# How to get the format of audio streams(WASAPI) of other processes - Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, api

In Windows, one can see the volume used by each audio-playing program in sndvol.exe. Is there a way to get more detailed information such as sampling rate and bits per sample? I want to know whether they are up/downsampled by audiodg.exe.